# WordPress My theme options settings not saving

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I just created a simple theme option page that is working fine and also saved after when press save options.

But when I go somewhere else from theme options page and come back to theme options page that settings what I saved just disappear and I have to change that again whenever I come to theme options page.

**Here is my code**

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'theme_options_add_page' );

if ( get_option('new_theme_options')) {
$theme_options = get_option('new_theme_options');
} else {
add_option('new_theme_options', array (
    'sidebar2_on' => true,
    'footer_text' => ''
));
$theme_options = get_option('new_theme_options');

}

function theme_options_add_page() {
add_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'My Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 8,    'themeoptions', 'theme_options_do_page' );
}

function theme_options_do_page() {
global  $theme_options;



    $new_values = array (
        'footer_text' => htmlentities($_POST['footer_text'], ENT_QUOTES),
        );
update_option('new_theme_options', $new_values);

$theme_options = $new_values;

?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <?php screen_icon(); echo "<h2>" . get_current_theme() . __( ' Theme   Options', 'responsivetheme' ) . "</h2>"; ?>




 <form method="post" action="themes.php?page=themeoptions">

 <label for="footer_text">Footer Text:</label>
 <input id="footer_text" type="text" name="footer_text" value="<?php echo   $theme_options['footer_text']; ?>" />

    <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e( 'Save Options', 'responsivetheme' ); ?>" />
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
 <?php
}
```

Comment: Where are you using this code? What happens if you disable all plugins? Did you test using the code in a clean theme? Any messages from `WP_DEBUG`?

Comment: yes my theme is clean and I am using it in funcions.php and I dont have much plugins and I am also using it on localhost.
I did not enable WP_DEBUG.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: defaults in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\responsive-theme\functions.php on line 88`

`Notice: Undefined variable: new_values in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\responsive-theme\functions.php on line 359`

`Notice: Undefined variable: new_values in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\responsive-theme\functions.php on line 361`

this is the msgs from WP_DEBUG

Comment: Ok, than you have to handle this Notices accordingly, using `isset()` mainly and providing alternatives when the var does not exist yet. Can you test my code on another theme that you haven't modified? It works for me and your problem seems to be elsewhere, outside the sample code you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Praveen answer is correct, but for completeness I'll post the full code I tested. Please, note that you should *always* develop with [`WP_DEBUG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) enabled. It shows three issues with your code:

- using `$_POST['footer_text']` without it being defined (Praveen's answer)
- using the deprecated function `get_current_theme()`
- using Level instead of Capability in `add_submenu_page()`

I dropped the following code into my theme's `functions.php` and it works ok:

```
if ( get_option('new_theme_options')) {
    $theme_options = get_option('new_theme_options');
} else {
    $theme_options = array (
        'sidebar2_on' => true,
        'footer_text' => ''
    );
    add_option( 'new_theme_options', $theme_options );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'theme_options_add_page' );

function theme_options_add_page() {
    add_submenu_page( 
        'themes.php', 
        'My Theme Options', 
        'Theme Options', 
        'add_users',    
        'themeoptions', 
        'theme_options_do_page' 
    );
}

function theme_options_do_page() {
    global  $theme_options;
    if( isset( $_POST['footer_text'] ) ) {
        $new_values = array (
            'footer_text' => htmlentities( $_POST['footer_text'], ENT_QUOTES),
        );
        update_option('new_theme_options', $new_values);
        $theme_options = $new_values;
    } 
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php screen_icon(); echo "<h2>" . wp_get_theme() . __( ' Theme   Options', 'responsivetheme' ) . "</h2>"; ?>
        <form method="post" action="themes.php?page=themeoptions">
            <label for="footer_text">Footer Text:</label>
            <input id="footer_text" type="text" name="footer_text" value="<?php echo   $theme_options['footer_text']; ?>" />
            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e( 'Save Options', 'responsivetheme' ); ?>" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

The only issue I can see is the option value `sidebar2_on` that's being overwritten in `theme_options_do_page()`, but your sample code does not show it being used elsewhere.

Comment: @Mr.beginner, glad to know :) Always keep an eye on the debugger notices and warnings. That, and proper code indentation, makes life much more easier. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, that is really more helpful. :) :D

Comment: what should i add instead `if( isset( $_POST['footer_text'] ) )` if I want to add more options in below array?

`if( isset( $_POST['footer_text'] ) ) {
        $new_values = array (
            'footer_text' => htmlentities( $_POST['footer_text'], ENT_QUOTES),
        );
        update_option('new_theme_options', $new_values);
        $theme_options = $new_values;
    } `

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41689/how-to-save-wordpress-options-as-an-array

Answer (score 1):

Please change this code:

```
if($_POST['footer_text']) {
$new_values = array (
    'footer_text' => htmlentities($_POST['footer_text'], ENT_QUOTES),
    );
update_option('new_theme_options', $new_values);
$theme_options = $new_values;
}
```

hope this will work fine :)

Comment: Use this plugin -- http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

you can add new fields by the help of this plugin in any page, Please try this one.

Comment: I dont want to use plugins , I want to correct my code by peoples help on here.